# Conversion of first order logic

Tags: first-order-logic

How to convert sentence with Existential quantification into sentence without quantifiers given domain D={3,4} ?

I found the solution for ∃Xq(X) => q(3) U q(4)

Now I am stuck when it comes to conversion of binary predicate: ∃X∀Y p(X, Y )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Over the domain $D = \{3,4\}$ we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\exists X \forall Y p(X,Y) & \equiv (\forall Y p(3, Y)) \vee (\forall Y p(4,Y)) \\
& \equiv (p(3,?) \wedge p(3,?)) \vee (\forall Y p(4,Y)) \\
& \equiv \ldots
\end{align*}
$$

[Fill in the "$?$" and complete the conversion.]

Comment: hmm... Am I supposed to fill in X in the place of "?" I am sorry because this is totally new to me. And also why X is not added to the expansion?? but you have Y

Comment: No, you are supposed to fill in the right elements of $D$.

Comment: And also why X is not added to the expansion?? but you have Y

Comment: The $Y$ is still there because I'm only showing you the first few steps of the conversion. In the end there will be no $X$ or $Y$ left in the formula.

Comment: alright now I understood.  ∃X∀Yp(X,Y)≡(∀Yp(3,Y))∨(∀Yp(4,Y))≡(p(3,?)∧p(3,?))∨(∀Yp(4,Y))≡(p(3,3)∧p(3,4))∨(p(4,3))∧p(4,4)) ??

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: That's great! Thank you very much for the clarification :)

Comment: You're welcome!